# Dashboards: show list of leads counted in graph

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, dashboard

Say I have a graph that looks like this on a dashboard in Salesforce:

[image: graph1]

How can I display, preferably color-coded, the leads counted in it (i.e., the ones talked about in the graph)? Like to the right of it or similar? Happy to write my own component or similar, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Lead Report using Standard Leads report type.
2. Use Summary Format for your report
3. Add Issue Rate and Lead Generation Date as your Group fields
4. Group your date field by Month
   [image]
5. Add a chart within the report. On your X-Axis, put the Date that you've used. Then on Group By use whatever you want your records to be grouped by in this example I've used Lead Status. 
   [image: Lead]
6. Save your report
7. You can create the same chart within your dashboard. Or you can just tick the "Use chart as defined in the source report" option to replicate what's already on your report
   [image: Chart]

If you want to learn more about creating reports and dashboards you can take this module from Salesforce Trailhead: 
[Reports & Dashboards](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/module/reports_dashboards)

Cheers